# Problems with WebPack on Electron

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

There is HTML code:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src = "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin> </script>
<script src = "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin> </script>
<script src = "https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"> </script>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title> WarehouseApp </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class = "topPanel">
</div>
<div id = "root" />
<script src = "scripts / main-panel.js" type = "text / babel"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which calls React code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App.jsx'
import Table from './table.js'
import TableDropdown from './toolbar.js'

class MainPanel extends React.Component {

render () {
return <div>
<div class = "toolBar">
<div id = "tableDropdown"> </div>
<div>
Search:
<input type = "text" />
</div>
<div> Audit Trail </div>
<div> 127.0.0.1:3000 </div>
<div>
<button class = "button"> Remove </button>
<button class = "button"> Add </button>
<button class = "button"> Wizard </button>
</div>
</div>
<TableDropdown />
<Table />
</div>
}

}

ReactDOM.render (<MainPanel />, document.getElementById ('root'));
```

The problem is in the first lines of React code, in imports. The program on them is interrupted and gives the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

The app is powered by Electron.

Re-installed WebPack, unfortunately it did not help.

I tried write to the index.js:

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
})
win.show()
```

But it didn't work for me.

Comment: Try adding contextIsolation: false under web preferences.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me partially, but now there is another problem in that nested (table.js, toolbar.js) files are not perceived as React code. Unexpected Token Error.

Comment: Okay so I’m not familiar with those frameworks but I did had similar issues with jQuery and adding this line before my jQuery Script is called helped: <script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>